# Hide an element and show another if page is taking too long to load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, replace, timer, load

Is there a way to hide an element and then show another instead if the page is taking too long to fully load?
Situation: I have a header with a background video, and if someone has a slow connection and the background video cannot load, then replace the header element with another header that has a static background image.

Thanks

Comment: you need to include an attempt you have made at this so we can debug: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do it the other way round. Show the static image and once the video has loaded replace the image with the video. That way if it doesn't load you've still got the image showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not something I'd usually recommend but here's a pretty hacky solution.

```
const video = document.querySelector("#video-element-id");

let tooSlow = false;

let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  tooSlow = true;
  
  ...logic to change header

  clearTimeout(timeout);
}, 1000);

video.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
  console.log(tooSlow ? 'too slow' : 'loaded');
  clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

* EDIT - or you could do the same with a promise tbf

```
const video = document.querySelector("#video-element-id");

const loader = new Promise((resolve) => {
  let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(false);
    }, 0);

  video.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
      resolve(true);
    });
});

loader
  .then((isLoaded) => {
    if (isLoaded) {
      console.log('loaded');
      
      return;
    }
    
    console.log('too slow');

    ...logic to change header
  });
```

There's still the issue that the video will continue to download even after the header has been switched though. A better solution might be to use the `poster` attribute to show a still image of the video until it's finished loading :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster